# How to save Microsoft Word document formatting as a template?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

So, basically, I'll make a copy of the current document. I want the text replaced by text boxes (or equivalents), but whatever I type in that text box must retain the formatting of the original text.

All lines/dividers must remain the same, only the *text* is affected.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the Word 2016 document, go to File and Save As.

Choose "Word Template (*.dotx) from the File Type drop down list.

[image: Word 2016 Save As Template]